# How to correct scale autocad file in Blender

Tags: 3d-view, import, scale

I have a autocad file and imported in Blender. After click the Import button i dont know the size is small or large. After going to outliner and selecting the mesh and click the dot button i can view my plan. But its cut off when pan and cant see the units in **Feets**. How to get the exact scale and units in Blender as compare to Autocad file.

**Imported converted in Blender**

[image]

[Autocad File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wkUDudPbHi-O1HhPNjoTlxgDe8vG-GoZ)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to have correct lengths you need to define and convert units correctly. In any computer software package lengths are measured using floating point numbers that do not have any meaning on their own like for example 15.758, or 3, or 250.5. In one way or another a unit like a meter, a nanometer, a foot, a lightyear or anything else needs to be assigned to the numbers so for example 1 becomes 1 meter, 2 becomes 2 meters and so on. In different programs or even different contexts using the same software different units are used. They need to be converted correctly.

First of all you need to know what units are used in the files you have. Then you also need to choose what units you want to use in Blender:

[image]

When you know these two things - the units in your files and the units you are using in Blender - you will know if you need any conversion when importing.

For example: the interior designers I work with are used to working in millimeters, however I work in meters in Blender. I ask them to export the drawings in meters to DXF and they do so. I do not need to adjust anything and get the scale correctly when importing.

If they exported the drawings in millimeters I would need to set the unit scale to 0.001 when importing because a millimeter is 0.001 of a meter.
Same goes for feet - I would set the unit scale to 0.3048 if I chose to work in meters.

[image]

You could also scale the units. If it's feet that need to be converted to meters you would select the imported curves and hit <kbd>s</kbd> followed by <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>8</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have imported the file and converted to mesh and scale as mention above 0.3048 but problem im getting in the original Autocad file the window size is 6'3" but in blender im getting 75ft. Where im going wrong.

Comment: What are the units in Autocad and what units are you working with in Blender?

Comment: Its 6 feet and 3 inch and same i want in Blender but its showing 75ft with the Measureit addon

Comment: Am not talking about the size of the object - that is irrelevant. I am talking about the mesurement units set in Autocad and units set in Blender.

Comment: I have measure in sketchup also here is the difference https://imgur.com/gallery/1edI1XE

Comment: Plz check new file attach what going wrong

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the file. Everything is working exactly as intended. The imported data was set to the wrong size - that is all. Please see the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for replying i get above mention. Is it possible i want to work as seen in sketchup shown in feet. Same unit or display seen in sketchup i want in blender. In sketchup its seen 6ft and 3inch same way i want in Blender.

Comment: I have created a cube 1ft in sketchup and imported and got the same unit and scale without any scale. https://imgur.com/gallery/ATEnAvv